# How do I create an application form line using css and html

Tags: html, css

Hi friends I am trying to create an application form line using html and css, it should look like below image. 
As I will be wrapping it in pdf so will it be necessory to put everything in table? can anyone please help me? How do I create exact application line like belwo image.
here is what I have tried `[demo][1]`

Here is my updated code, but I dont think position absolute will work in pdf so please html me to get this in pdf.

```
<table>
            <tr>
               <h3 style="position:relative">Signed at_________, this __________</h3>
               <span style="position: absolute;top: 40px;left: 110px;font-weight: bold;">ville</span>
                <span style="    position: absolute;top: 40px;left: 240px;font-weight: bold;">date</span>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

[image]

Her is [Fiddle to try](https://jsfiddle.net/b6kp20q6/2/)

Comment: share your code which you have already tried

Comment: It's interesting both css approaches failed.  What software are you using to convert to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the table text needs to be in a `<td>` tag. I would add a class to the table to control the font-size and boldness to prevent using `<h3>`s everywhere.

```css
table {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

.row-form {
  background-color: #ffff00; 
}

.row-description {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row-form">
    <td>Signed at</td>
    <td>________________</td>
    <td>, this&nbsp</td>
    <td>________________</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-description">
    <td></td>
    <td>ville</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and answer but its not coming same when I convert into pdf. :-(

Comment: Thank you for reply and it worked after little css but your structure of table did the trick, plus +10 for that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it depends on what you're planning to di exactly. But relative positioning in CSS is very powerful, e.g.

```
<p>
This is a line with <span class="inputline"><span class="subtext">some attribute</span></span> spacing.
</p>
```

With this CSS

```
span.inputline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
span.subtext {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1.1em;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

View result here: https://jsfiddle.net/36vkf34h/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and answer but its not coming same when I convert into pdf. :-(

Comment: Thanks for reply here I am voting you 10+ for answering my question and teaching something new about position relative, I will remember this. But table structure from prev answer worked for me